# Facing some issue while executing behat command from jenkins(Execute shell)

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, behat

when I execute behat command on execute shell on jenkins, it gives me following error.

**

```
"BUILD FAILED
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/behat/behatTest/build.xml:5: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "behat": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Java13CommandLauncher.java:58)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:428)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:442)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:629)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:670)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:496)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:853)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:285)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:112)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 24 more"
```

**
 I can easily run behat command from command line on amazon ec2 server.

Comment: Which version of  `Behat` you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling behat command from Ant?

Try to use absolute `behat` path in your ant script.

It would be helpful if you would also post your Ant script.

Comment: Hi lichensky,  
Thanks for your reply, actually I don't have much knowledge about behat script and testing. I am implementing automation testing for my project on amazon ec2.

Comment: What is the exact step that you are executing on Jenkins?
I assume that you are running Ant script because of stacktrace.
Could you check `behat/behatTest/build.xml` file in your workspace? It should contains ant build setup.

Comment: 1). I have installed behat  on amazon ec2 server ubuntu using method 1 mentioned on below link http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/quick_intro.html 

2)after following above method my root folder(/home/ubuntu) on amazon ec2 server contains following files 
1. bin  2. composer.json  3. composer.lock  4. composer.phar  5. vendor
behat 2.5 is installed on the server successfully.

Comment: 3) then I execute behat --init command inside my project folder it contains features folder in which i have put one simple script file. now if I run behat command in command line I get below output

Comment: Given I am in a directory "test"    # FeatureContext::iAmInADirectory()
    And I have a file named "foo"       # FeatureContext::iHaveAFileNamed()
    And I have a file named "bar"       # FeatureContext::iHaveAFileNamed()
    When I run "ls"                     # FeatureContext::iRun()
    Then I should get:                  # FeatureContext::iShouldGet()
      """
      bar
      foo
      """
      Actual output is:
      bar
      features
      foo

Comment: 2 scenarios (1 undefined, 1 failed)
16 steps (4 passed, 11 undefined, 1 failed)
0m0.031s

but If run the same command from execute shell in jenkins it gives me the above mentioned error.

Comment: in short behat command running in command line amazon ec2 but not working when I try to execute it from execute shell jenkins